# PowerPivot VBA - Populating ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, powerpivot

I am trying to create a VBA UserForm that will filter and display data being pulled from an Azure SQL Database. The database view that is being connected has about 8 million rows in total and I want to filter those records using a user friendly interface. My users are not going to be able to / want to manipulate the PowerPivot data model.

So my question is, is there a way to populate a ComboBox with unique values, or any values, in a PowerPivot linked table? I would prefer to keep the data in the model and not displayed on a "Settings" page. Some of them will have quite a few rows themselves.

Would my best option be to query the SQL database directly when loading the form? Or can I pull records from the PowerPivot data model?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the data out of PowerPivot through vba. You'll have to query the source.